# Winscp - need to set up new company

Tags: winscp, microsoft-dynamics

Forgive me in advance for not presenting this question in a more knowledgeable way.

I've been tasked with "setting up a new company" in Winscp (or to utilize) Winscp to move banking ACH / EFT / Prenote files. We utilize MS Dynamics / Great Plains.

Can anyone advise me on where to begin? Any help you could offer would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: WinSCP knows nothing about "companies". It transfers files to or from a Windows client machine. It sounds like you're trying to specify a piece of software before you know what you do with it, and I'd suggest you garner more information from your internal business analyst.

Comment: What exact help you need? The WinSCP is pretty simple and intuitive program. You creating in bookmark "account" and on the right side you just have to set correct parameters to remote server, when you connected there are concept of "Norton Commander" - two panels where one showing your hard drive and another remote drive. Buttons in the bottom remind you - what key you need to press for specific action. Be more descriptive, edit your question and add more info, - where you got stack, otherwise it really hard to guess what you want.

Comment: I think you need NOTEPAD.EXE

Answer (score 2):

WinSCP is a file transfer program – it doesn't have the concept of companies, nor is it in any way related to banking. So the question needs a lot more context to make sense. *A lot* more.

WinSCP is compatible with SFTP (SSH file transfer) servers, FTPS (FTP-TLS) servers, and the occassional SCP/FTP/WebDAV server. It is similar to e.g. FileZilla.

Possibly your organization already uses (runs or has access to) an SFTP or FTPS server which holds those banking files, and possibly has a user account per company (or at least a folder per company).

Beyond that, the task you described is specific to your organization's internal systems – not something that the general public can easily guess or help with.